# Trying to install agent-protocol for autogpt

Tags: python, chatgpt-api, autogpt

I have been trying to run the requirments.txt file fould at https://github.com/Significant-Gravitas/Auto-GPT/blob/stable/requirements.txt
I am not able to  install agent protocol

```
(.venv) ayushyaverma@Ayushyas-MacBook-Pro Auto-GPT % pip install agent-protocol

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement agent-protocol (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for agent-protocol
```

I even tried to install with repositary

```
(.venv) ayushyaverma@Ayushyas-MacBook-Pro Auto-GPT % pip install git+https://github.com/AI-Engineers-Foundation/agent-protocol/tree/main/sdk/python  
Collecting git+https://github.com/AI-Engineers-Foundation/agent-protocol/tree/main/sdk/python
  Cloning https://github.com/AI-Engineers-Foundation/agent-protocol/tree/main/sdk/python to /private/var/folders/1b/8pjfld0j6jn_spvg3s0tzdz80000gn/T/pip-req-build-ane50soj
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/AI-Engineers-Foundation/agent-protocol/tree/main/sdk/python /private/var/folders/1b/8pjfld0j6jn_spvg3s0tzdz80000gn/T/pip-req-build-ane50soj
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/AI-Engineers-Foundation/agent-protocol/tree/main/sdk/python/' not found
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/AI-Engineers-Foundation/agent-protocol/tree/main/sdk/python /private/var/folders/1b/8pjfld0j6jn_spvg3s0tzdz80000gn/T/pip-req-build-ane50soj did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 128
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/AI-Engineers-Foundation/agent-protocol/tree/main/sdk/python /private/var/folders/1b/8pjfld0j6jn_spvg3s0tzdz80000gn/T/pip-req-build-ane50soj did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 128
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

this is the page of agent-prtocol on github
https://agentprotocol.ai/clients/python

please help

I tried the to run to satisfy the requirements and was expecting it would install it

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same issue while running pip install for auto-gpt.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrl9i.png)

steps to fix ->

1. goto https://github.com/AI-Engineers-Foundation/agent-protocol
   clone the repo
2. goto path /agent-protocol/sdk/python
3. run `pip install .` or `pip3 install .`

This fixed the issue for me.
[after above steps output of pip install -r requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDtCN.png)

PS:- i suggest using docker for simplicity and easy setup. you just need to run few commands and you are good to go.

ref -> [link to docker setup](https://docs.agpt.co/setup/#run-with-docker)

Comment: this is the only way I found worked !

Comment: Docker compose build has the same broken dependencies.

Comment: The SDK has been moved here https://github.com/AI-Engineer-Foundation/agent-protocol-sdk-python/tree/main